# Was bedeutet "ein grüner Zweig" in dieser Redewendung: es auf einen grünen Zweig bringen

Tags: meaning, usage, idiom

Was ist gemeint, wenn jemand sagt:

> So kommst du nie auf einen **grünen Zweig.**

Was bedeutet: ein grüner Zweig in diesem Zusammenhang? Woher stammt dieser Ausdruck?

Comment: Du meinst, "wenn man es auf einen grünen Zweig gebracht hat", sollte man "nicht auf den Lorbeeren sitzen bleiben"?
Danke für den Hinweis! Das beweist, wie wichtig solche obsoleten Fragen und  Klärungen in einem deutschsprachigen SE sein können. Ich hoffe, jemand von den Admin.  hat das hier gelesen.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: für grundsätzliche Diskussionen gibt es unser [Meta], das Du bestimmt schon gesehen hast. Du wirst dort einige interessante Beiträge gerade auch zum Thema Close- und Down-Votes finden und so vielleicht auch einen Einblick in die Grundprinzipien der S.E.-Seiten erhalten. Wir Moderatoren möchten so wenig wie möglich eingreifen. So gut wie alles wird hier über die Community geregelt; das klappt auch ganz gut. Nur wenn die Community nicht weiter kommt, dann springen wir Moderatoren ein. Hier an diesem Beitrag ist doch alles gut, oder?

Comment: @ Takkat: Klar, danke. Ich habe den Punkt in obigem Punkt erwähnt: ob eine Frage obsolet sei oder nicht, bzw. die Antwort für ander User von Nutzen sein könnte.

Comment: Man vergleiche den *aufsteigenden/absteigenden Ast*, die Verwandschaft von *grün* mit En *grow* "wachsen"; Vermute einen Zusammenhang zum *family tree* (Stammbaum), *branche* o.ä., oder etwa *Abzweigung, Weg* (\*Zweg?). Grün ist die Hoffnung und so, two roads diverged in a *yellow* wood, cp IE \*ǵʰelh₃ "grün, gelb, hell, wachsen"; cp \*gel- (to yell; cold, "Eis"), \*kel- (to call), *das singende klingende Bäumchen*, Baum als Sinnbild der Familie, einer Tochter, Adam und Eva ... *Ruf* (En fame<[Rede]), *famine* "Hunger", Lt *famula* (weibl. Gefolge>Familie), En *to cling* (halten; cp Haushalt).

Comment: Denkbar ist, der in den Antworten beschriebe Brauch entwuchs einer redensart.

Answer (score 6):

Die Redewendung "auf keinen grünen Zweig kommen" bedeutet

- keinen Erfolg haben,
- kein Glück haben,
- sich keine solide Lebensgrundlage schaffen,
- es zu nichts bringen,
- sich nicht (finanziell) absichern

Häufig bringt die Redewendung auch zum Ausdruck, dass es jemand generell im Leben zu nichts bringt.

Als Herkunft der Redewendung wird angegeben, dass der grüne Zweig im Volksglauben von jeher ein Symbol der Fruchtbarkeit und damit ein immergrüner Zweig etwas Besonderes ist. Entstanden ist die Redewendung aus dem Brauch, bei dem Haus- oder Grundstücksverkäufer den neuen Besitzern einen Zweig von immergrünen Bäumen überreichten, (beispielsweise Buchsbaum, Eibe oder ein Nadelbaum). Laut Volksglauben zogen die guten Geister, die in den immergrünen Bäumen wohnten, mit in das neue Haus ein.

Wer aber zu arm war, sich ein Haus zu kaufen, kam nie "auf einen grünen Zweig" und somit nicht an einen guten Geist, der einem Glück und Erfolg bringen konnte.

Comment: +1
gut, darf ich die Frage editieren? sie lautet im Titel: was bedeutet "ein grüner Zweig".
Für mich impliziert dies die Frage nach der Herkunft, sorry.

Comment: Es ist vielleicht einen Kommentar wert, dass diese Aussage nur in der **negativen** Form auftaucht. *Es auf einen grünen Zweig bringen* scheint nicht vorzukommen.

Comment: @ guidot: nicht nur in negativen! Bsp.:
"Wer finanziell auf einen grünen Zweig kommen […] will, muss sich von der bäuerlichen Betriebsführung verabschieden und industrielle Managementmethoden einführen. (Frédéric de Reynal, Präsident des größten Bananenerzeugerverbands auf Martinique)[

Answer (score 2):

Woher sie kommt - hmm, diese Frage lässt sich wie alle solche Fragen kaum oder nicht beantworten. In der Regel lässt sich jedoch sagen, wann etw. das erste Mal belegt ist.

> Die Rda. ist seit dem Ende des 15. Jh. belegt, z.B. in Seb.[astian]
> Brants *Narrenschiff*:
>
> **Erberkeyt muosz verr hynden stan und kumbt gar kum uff grünen zwig**
>
> *erberkeyt = Ehrbarkeit; verr = weit; das y hat den Lautwert i*

Lutz Röhrich. *Lex. d. sprichw. Redensarten*, Bd. 5.

Da steht auch einiges über diverse Vermutungen zum Ursprung, und der Röhrich steht bestimmt in einer der Bibliotheken an deinem Wohnort. Ich hab' grade keine Lust, das alles abzutippen. ;-)

Fragen dieser oder ähnlicher Art lassen sich in der Regel auch mithilfe des GRIMM klären: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/
Auch der ältere ADELUNNG kann hilfreich sein: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Adelung/  Das DWDS sagt gelegentlich etwas zur Etymologie: http://www.dwds.de/

Wenn du noch Fragen hast, hinterlass' bitte eine Notiz; die sehe ich dann in den Mails.

**edit:** Ich sehe gerade, dass tofro Röhrichs weitere Ausführungen zusammengefasst wiedergegeben hat. Spart dir evtl. den Weg in die Bib. ;-)

Comment: +1 für das Recherchieren und die Angabe interessanter Quellen!
Nein, in die Bibliothek zu  gehen brauch ich nicht, danke ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ich [finde](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~auf%20keinen%20gr%C3%BCnen%20Zweig%20kommen&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=rart_varianten_ou) zu der Redewendung die (unbelegte, aber plausible) Erklärung, dass ein grüner Zweig schon seit alters her als Symbol der Fruchtbarkeit und des Wachstums (und damit indirekt, Reichtum) dient. Die Redensart ginge auf den Brauch zurück, nachdem Erwerber von Grundeigentum und Immobilien vom Verkäufer einen grünen Zweig als 
Symbol für Fruchtbarkeit und Wachstum überreicht bekamen. (Das Schmücken des Dachfirsts mit einem grünen Zweig beim Richtfest scheint auf einen ähnlichen oder den gleichen Brauch zurückzugehen).

Wer also "nie auf einen grünen Zweig" kam, kam nie zu Grundbesitz und damit relativen Reichtum, oder im übertragenen Sinne, kam nie zu Erfolg.

Comment: +1 für die Angabe des links! Wenn du darin noch einen Hinweis für den möglichen Ursprung postest, kannst du dir sicher noch einen Punkt holen.